# Reference Type comparison in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, reference-type

I am trying to understand below problem. I want to know why `B == A` and `C == B` are false in the following program.

```
using System;

namespace Mk
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int i = 10;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 A = new Class1();
            Class1 B = new Class1();
            Class1 C = A;

            Console.WriteLine(B == A);
            Console.WriteLine(C == B);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> False
>   False

Comment: Please explain why the results you got surprised you.

Comment: Because I realize this concept was not clear in my mind. But now i am satisfied with below answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, classes are *reference types*. Reference types has two thing. ***Object*** and a ***reference to object***.

In your case, `A` is a reference to the `ObjectA`, `B` is a reference to the `ObjectB`.

When you define `Class1 C = A;`

> - First, you create two thing. An object called **ObjectC** and a reference to the object called **C**.
> - Then you copy reference of `A` to reference of `C`. Now, **A and C is reference to the same object**.

When you use `==` with reference objects, if they reference to the same objets, it returns `true`, otherwise return `false`.

In your case, that's why `B == A` and `C == B` returns `false`, but if you tried with `A == C`, it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One  more thing which now i am thinking of, C.Equals(A) and C==A are same ?

Comment: @MazharKhan If `C.Equals(A)` returns `true`, It doesn't mean `C` is equal to `A`. It means `C` and `A` are reference to the same object. Because `A` and `C` are just reference. They are NOT objects. Read [Object.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

A and B are different objects.  They are of the same class, but not the same instance.  Just like two people can both be people, but they are not the same person.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the references of the two class instances.  Since A and B reside at different memory locations their references are not equal.  If you want to test class equality you will need to override the `Equals()` method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

In your example if you were to test `A == C` you would see it return `true` since they both point to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct as you are trying to compare the reference. Here A and B are different objects and hence they result in false on comparison.A, B all are at different memory locations and hence their references are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

References types hold the address in memory. In your case A and B completely point to different addresses. However, C is pointing to the same address as A does since you assign A to C.