# What could be wrong with my if else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
 Card img = new Card();
   Deck im = new Deck();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bc;// = new Bitmap(100, 142);

        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        Card[] card = im.Shuffling();

        bc = img.DrawCard(card[1]);
```

> eventhough  the Color1 property is == to b the the compiler still skips to the else statment, even if i use the not(!=) function all components still go in the if statment. Where could i be going wrong?

```
        if (card[1].Color1== b)
        {

            pic = new PictureBox();
            piclist = new List<PictureBox>();


            numberOfCards++;

            piclist.Add(pic);

            this.Controls.Add(pic);
            pic.Size = pictureBox1.Size;
            pic.Left = pictureBox1.Left + ((pictureBox1.Width) * numberOfCards);
            pic.Top = pictureBox1.Top;
            pic.Visible = true;
            pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            pic.BringToFront();

            pic.Image = bc;



        }
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("unequall");




    }
```

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging this problem? What's the behavior that you see and what's expected?

Comment: What type is `Card.Color1`? It sounds like a `Color`, which then makes sense that it wouldn't be equal to a `SolidBrush`. Unless they specifically override that operator for that, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: `Brush` is a reference type, and is likely not being compared in depth as you would expect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004817/reference-type-comparison-in-c-sharp

Comment: The `==` operator checks reference values rather than the actual value of the two class instances, since even two "identical" class instances are unlikely to be exactly the same unless one is a clone of the other.  Try `card[1].Color1.Name == b.Name` or some similar value type identifier for the class.

Comment: `SolidBrush` does not overload `==` so you're testing for reference equality, which can't possibly be true since you've just created the instance to compare with.

Comment: I have debugged the problem, even though the compiler shows that they are equal it still skips  to the else

Comment: Did you drop `card[1].Color1== b` into a watch window and confirm it's `true`?

Comment: Color1 is also type brush @MatthewHaugen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is `Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);` generates a new object, and `card[1].Color1` is a different reference to a different SolidBrush instance.  The comparison does NOT check that they are the same color, but checks that they are the same reference. If you search SO for "comparing reference types c#" you will find lots of questions addressing this scenario in different ways.

Only stepping through the code can confirm for sure if this is what you are seeing.  I don't see where `card[1].Color1` is set, so its anyone's guess, but **almost certainly it is a reference comparison issue**. As sukotto points out, in this case you probably really want to be comparing the Color enums(which avoids the issue of a reference comparison, and instead compares discrete values).

Comment: public Brush Color1
        {
            get { return _brush1; }
            set { _brush1 = value; }
        }

Comment: Instead of using brush i just used solidbrush

Answer (score 5):

(Since I don't have the rep to comment)
To piggy-back on AaronLS's reply, which seems to be the correct answer to me:
The SolidBrush object will have a property SolidBrush.Color which you are setting in the constructor call

```
Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
```

So when you are checking equality of the brush color and your card color you need to return the Color of the brush for comparison:

```
if (card[1].Color1== b.Color)
```

Although, even this may not be the case if card[x].Color1 is of a difference reference type.

Comment: Good answer.  However, I suspect Color1 is of type SolidBrush, if it compiled successfully, so my guess is it's just a poorly named property, and the actual fix is to drill into the Color property of the brush `if(card[1].Color1.Color == b.Color)`  What do you think?

Comment: @RofhiwaMusandiwa Did you try the code in my comment? What syntax error?

Comment: ya i did but the .Color does not appear in any of the instance

Comment: You might need to declare your Brush property as a SolidBrush instead or cast it.  Brush doesn't have a Color property. only Solid

Comment: Thank you very Much @AaronLS instead of brush i used solidbrush, it perfectly works!!!!